# get an image from local filesystem from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, file, servlets

I'm trying to get an image stored into a local filesystem. After that, I need to mount an html with this image from javascript.

So far, I'm getting the image with a servlet, and it's actually working as I can show the image in my JSP `<img width="120" src="<%=IncVars.getParameter("ruta0")%>myImageServlet">`

```
public class MyImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //get the file image
    File image = IncFunctions.getLogoFile();

    // Get content type
    String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(image.getName());

    // Init servlet response.
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(image.length()));
    // Write image content to response.
    Files.copy(image.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
}
//...
}
```

I'm trying to do the same to mount the html from a js function, but I can't find the way to generate a html with this image in my js function:

```
 function mountTicket(text, idControl, servletPath){
     document.getElementById(idControl).innerHTML = parseTicket(texto, imagePath);
     window.print();
 }

function parseTicket(texto, servletPath){

var textHtml = "";

 //Call the servlet
 $.get(servletPath, function(data) {
     textoHtml = "<img  width='120' src=" + data + "/>";
     textoHtml += "<br />";
 });    

  //..


  textoHtml += "<div";
  if (estilo != ""){
  textoHtml += " style=\"" + estilo + "\"";
  }         

  textoHtml += ">" + contenido + "</div>";  

  return textoHtml;
}
```

The data var get from the servlet are bytes, and it seems the js doesn't know how to interpret it. I've also tried to pass the path of the image, let's say "C:\myDirectory\myImage.png", but as I expected, it couldn't find it and show it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was easier than I thought. I don't need to call the servlet from my js code, I just need to add the image with the servlet path.
Something like this:

```
textoHtml  = "<div><img src='" + servletPath + "'> </div>" ;
```

And the browser will show the image.

Hope it can help someone with similar "issues"